# Microsoft Flow, email with table when .csv is saved in Sharepoint

Tags: power-automate

I pasted this [question here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Take-CSV-in-Sharepoint-folder-and-convert-to-table-in-body-of/m-p/2197729#M243711) and the suggestions have gotten me most of the way there, but I'm having trouble finishing it up could use Stack Overflow's help.

I have a flow that looks like this:
[image]

The basics are that I have R run a script once a day.  Every once and a while, that R script 'finds' something, and saves a .csv with the results into a sharepoint folder.

I'd love to have Flow email me the results of that .csv.  I've already previously figured out how to get Flow to email me a simple notification, or attach the file, but now I'd prefer that the table was IN the email.  Something like this:

[image]

**Where I am now:**

I've ALMOST got it to work.  The flow will trigger, it'll parse the data, it'll send me a table with some of the data in it, but it'll look messed up.  Either like this:

[image]

Where all of the csv data is crammed into one column.  Or more recently with these settings:

[image]

It'll put ALL of the csvdata in every column:

[image]

To be honest it makes sense its screwing up like that because you can see in the settings that it says csv data in every column, but if I try 'automatic' columns it fails with "the property 'columns' must be specified unless its an array'.

**In summary:**

How do I specify what goes into what column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a third party action: "Parse CSV". From the result of the subsequent steps, it looks like the contents is in JSON. Therefore, you can use the built-in Parse JSON action to read the output of the "parse CSV" action, after which you can access the individual fields to build the HTML table.